# Как распределить элементы из разных строк на всю ширину страницы?

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли как-то CSS кодом расставить блоки на разных строках так, чтобы первый блок был без отступа слева, а второй был прижат к правому краю?
Я смог сделать через margin-left, но это костыль :)

Что есть:

[image: Что имеется]

Что хотелось бы получить с помощью CSS кода:

[image: Что хотелось бы получить]

Comment: Через гриды можете сделать, но это тоже не очень красиво будет. А так, чем `margin-left` костыль?

Comment: Ну хотелось бы "автоматизировать" расстановку, а не писать для каждого элемента margin-left: 100px. Может как-то можно сделать что-то типо :nth-child(1): margin-left: calc?

Comment: Ну тут через js (vue/angular/react/svelte) проще, если автоматизировать. а через CSS будут скорее костыли. Ну, если уровней неогранченное количество. Если ограниченное (4-5 штук), то можно и закостылить, ничего страшного нет в этом

Comment: Кол-во ограниченное - 4-5 штук как раз будет))